# How can I find out who offered the last interest rate at auction?

Tags: script, html, source-code

I want to know who else is participating at online auction but the name of the participant who offered the last interest rate is hidden with asterisks. Here's the script code from the source page:

```
jQuery("#w0").inputmask(inputmask_c2e8893e);

        
        function getServerTime() {
          return $.ajax({async: false}).getResponseHeader( 'Date' );
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/auctions/auction-offer-refresh",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                auctionId: 743, 
                _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken(),
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {

                    $("#departmentName").html(data.departmentName);
                    $("#bestOfferedPercentage").html( data.bestOfferedPercentage+' %');
                    $("#createdTime").html(data.createdTime);
                    $("#endTime").html(data.endTime);

                    // console.log(data);

                    var countDownDate = new Date(data.endTime).getTime();
                    var x = setInterval(function() {
//                      var now = new Date().getTime();
                        var now = new Date(getServerTime()).getTime();
                        
                        var distance = countDownDate - now;
                        
                        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                        //$("#downTime").html(days + " kun | " + hours + " soat | " + minutes + " daqiqa | " + seconds + " soniya");
                        $("#downTime").html(days + " k | " + hours + " s | " + minutes + " m | " + seconds + " s");
                        if ( (distance < 0) || isNaN(distance) ) {
                            clearInterval(x);
                            $("#downTime").html("Auksion nihoyasiga yetdi!");
                            $("#sendOffer").hide();
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/auctions/auction-offer-refresh",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                auctionId: 743, 
                                _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken(),
                            },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data2) {
                                var beginTime = new Date(data2.beginTime).getTime();
                                // $("#departmentName").html(data2.departmentName);
                                if (data2.ownerPerc) {
                                    $("#departmentName").html(data2.departmentName);
                                }  else {
                                    $("#departmentName").html("* * * *");
                                };
                                $("#bestOfferedPercentage").html( data2.bestOfferedPercentage+' %');
                                $("#createdTime").html(data2.createdTime);
//                                $("#endTime").html(data2.endTime);
                                countDownDate = new Date(data2.endTime).getTime();
                                var beginTime = new Date(data2.beginTime).getTime();
//                                now = new Date().getTime();
                                var now = new Date(getServerTime()).getTime();
                                if ( (now > beginTime) && (now < countDownDate) ) {
                                    $("#sendOffer").show();
                                }
                                $("#endTime").html(data2.endTime);
                            },
                        });

                        var url = "/uzasbo-auction-lots/server-side-time";
                        var _h = 0;
                        var _m = 0;
                        var _s = 0;
                        $.ajax({ 
                            url: url,
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'JSON', 
                            success: function(res) {

                                h = parseInt(res.hour)+_h;
                                m = parseInt(res.minute)+_m;
                                s = parseInt(res.second)+_s;
                            
                                if (s>59){                  
                                    s=s-60;
                                    _s=_s-60;                   
                                }
                            
                                if(s==59){
                                    _m++;   
                                }
                            
                                if (m>59){
                                    m=m-60;
                                    _m=_m-60;                   
                                }
                            
                                if(m==59&&s==59){
                                    _h++;   
                                }   
                            
                                _s++;
                            
                                $('#server_time').html(append_zero(h)+':'+append_zero(m)+':'+append_zero(s));               
                            
                                function append_zero(n){
                                    if(n<10){
                                        return '0'+n;
                                    } else {
                                        return n;
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        });

                    }, 1000);
            
                } 
                    
            },
                
        });
            
    
});</script>    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no name obfuscation logic in the code snippet you've posted.

It's not surprising, as any half-decent programmer or architect should know that users will try this. The data would be sent from the server already obfuscated.

Comment: so there's no way?

Comment: I can't tell for sure without taking a look at the website myself, but I'm pretty confident there's no way if they know what they are doing.